# How to set zIndex of points in 3d scatter chart?

Tags: highcharts, z-index

i didn't understand how works "zIndex" in 3d scatter chart in Highcharts...
I ask you if is possible to set z-Index for each point of series.

I have tried in this way:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Reading',
        colorByPoint: true,                     
        data: coloriamo()}] 
        });
```

when

```
 function coloriamo() {
       var points = [];  
           points.push({
                marker: {
                states: {
                        hover: {                                
                            radius: 5,
                            radiusPlus: 0,
                            lineWidth: 0,
                            lineColor: null,
                            lineWidthPlus: 0,
                            fillColor: 'red'
                            }
                        },
                    fillColor: 'grey',

                    radius: 5
                },

                zIndex: zindice,
                magn: magn,
                luogo: luogo,
                data: data,
                x: X,
                y: ipo,
                z: Z
            });          

    return points;
}
```

The function that i posted here is more short than original. The original function is ok, only "zIndez" doesn't work.

**zIndex**'s value changes for each point, but in the chart zIndex (with the code on top) doesn't work, and i dont'know why...

Thanks

EDIT

here jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7ujLkg/

Comment: Could you create jsFiddle demo with that issue? Thanks.

Comment: I simply think it's a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3949). Thanks!

Comment: thanks Pawel. Is the first time that do you see this bug ? and when will it be resolved ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know ETA for this bug. If I would see that bug earlier, then I would report this back then ;)